# Android ListView height in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I have this one layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/legend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/BannerView"
        android:text="Legend"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/legend" >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/generateBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/list"
        android:text="Generate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But button is out of screen. How can I set `ListView` height to see button below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/legend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/BannerView"
        android:text="Legend"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/generateBtn"
        android:layout_below="@id/legend" >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@id/generateBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Generate" />

</RelativeLayout>
```